# React Native setState inside useEffect not triggering rerender

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to build a component for playing an audio file using Expo AV. Before the audio is available, I want the component to render with reduced opacity (opacity = 0.2). Once the audio loads, I want the button to go to full opacity. I try to make this happen using a useEffect hook (no dependencies, just want to load audio file once when the component mounts) and a state variable called 'isLoaded'. Here is the code:

```
const AudioPlayer = ({ containerStyle }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [voice, setVoice] = useState(undefined);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSound = async () => {
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(DEFAULT_AUDIO_PATH);
      setVoice(sound);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }
    fetchSound();
  }, []);

  const playSound = async () => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      try {
        voice.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(status => {
          status.didJustFinish ? setIsPlaying(false) : null;
        });
        setIsPlaying(true);
        await voice.replayAsync();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={isLoaded ? [styles.container, containerStyle] : [styles.unloaded, containerStyle]}
      onPress={playSound}>
      <View style={styles.icon_wrapper}>
        <FontAwesome
          name={isPlaying ? 'volume-up' : 'play'}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

The component opacity does not change until I press the button, at which point the component begins to render as expected, so clearly the isLoaded state is set from the useEffect hook. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue - it seems that there is a bug with TouchableOpacity where any opacity changes made to the element only trigger when the component is pressed.

To fix the issue, simply change TouchableOpacity to Pressable.